# How to use clang++ with GitHub actions on Windows

Tags: github, github-actions

I just started using GitHub Actions and created a workflow file. I chose `windows-latest` as my deployment OS and try to execute the following one-liner:

```
- name: Run a one-line script
        run: clang++ foo.cpp -O3 -o foo.exe
```

And `clang-cl` does not exist, neither does `clang-cl`. According to the documentation Clang is shipped, but where do I find it? Any help is highly appreciated!

```
Line |
   2 |  clang++ foo.cpp -O3 -o foo.exe
     |  ~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'clang++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
     | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
     | and try again.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `clang++` is not in the PATH and got discussed in the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/104) on GitHub.

> Currently, you can find clang/clang++ and other binaries, which possible absent in current MinGW installation, by paths:
>
> x64
> `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`
>
> x32
> `C:\msys64\mingw32\bin`
>
> In order to add them into the system PATH, please follow the steps below:
>
> **GitHub Actions:**
> `echo "::add-path::C:\msys64\mingw64\bin"`
>
> **Azure DevOps:** `echo '##vso[task.prependpath]C:\msys64\mingw64\bin'`

Comment: Seems this is no longer an option, shortly after this answer: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/